# Which Stack Exchange websites allow asking which websites can OCR a pdf file and embed the text in the pdf file?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Which Stack Exchange websites allow questions such as this one?

> what websites can OCR a pdf file and produce a copy of the pdf file with OCRed text embedded, other than archive.org (banned by GFW)?

webapps.stackexchange.com doesn't allow posts asking for recommendations.

Comment: I don't think there's a webapps equivalent of the software and hardware recs sites. They're the only real exception to the 'no shopping/recs' rule

Answer (score 3):

> Which Stack Exchange websites allow questions such as this one?

Webapps recommendation are on-topic on softwarerecs: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-apps?tab=Newest. You can ask  for a webapp to do what you described.